# Random numbers in Java when working with Android

Tags: java, android, integer

I need to make a random number between 1 and 20, and based on that number (using "If - Then" statements), I need to set the image of an ImageView.

I know that in Objective-C, it goes like this:

```
int aNumber = arc4Random() % 20;
if (aNumber == 1) {
    [theImageView setImage:theImage];
}
```

How can I do this in Java? I have seen it done this way, but I do not see how I can set the range of numbers (1-20, 2-7, ect).

```
int aNumber = (int) Math.random()
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Docs are your friends](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html)

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(20); // Gives n such that 0 <= n < 20
```

**Documentation**:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.
>   Thus, from this example, we'll have a number between 0 and 19

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to read the docs, but I am honestly lost on that website. I guess I am one of those people that can do the programming, but not the thinking lol.

Comment: could be even shorter: `int n = new Random().nextInt(20);`

Answer (score 7):

`Math.random()` returns an `double` from [0,1[.
`Random.nextInt(int)` returns an `int` from [0, int[.

Comment: @trutheality You caught me :P How can an `int` be between 0 and 1 anyways? ^^

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
int aNumber = (int) (20 * Math.random()) + 1;
```

or

```
Random rand = new Random();
int n = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
```

Comment: This looks like what I want, but the answer by @trutheality already has a vote. Is there anything better about this answer?

Comment: Nope. You can do both. But beware that you should add 1 if you want to start from 1 because it start from 0 (included) to 20 (excluded).

Comment: `Math.random` doesn't instantiate an object, whereas `new Random()` does.

Comment: Most implementations of `Math.random()` do create a `Random` object the first time they're called (and reuse it later). I'm having trouble finding the actual android implementation but I wouldn't be surprised if it does too. If you're going to worry about micro-optimization, note that with `Math.random` you're doing `double` arithmetic and then double-to-int conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.random() to generate a double between 0 and 1 non-inclusive. Android Javadoc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html#random()).